# cmake gets confused and thinks that build directory is source directory

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install `opencv` on my `raspberry pi 4` with `raspian OS`.

I am using this tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html and I have navigated to a build directory in my source directory `/home/icetea/Desktop/working_dir/opencv/build`

Then I execute this command:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/icetea/Desktop/working_dir/opencv`

I get this error:

`CMake Error: The source directory "/home/icetea/Desktop/working_dir/opencv/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt`

It thinks the build dir is the source dir. My source dir does 100% contain that .txt file, but my build dir is empty. I have tried executing this command while in the source dir and I get this error:

`FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed. You should create a separate directory for build files`

Anybody have any insight?

Thank you very much

Smitty

Comment: You need to add "../" or whatever relative path to specify the folder that contains your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Note that the link you copied from contains the same command as yours with two dots extra. They're important